# Iterating over and reducing values of a Java map via Stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, reduce

Java 8 here. I have an array of Strings:

```
String[] animals = getsomehow(); // "dogs", "cats", "sheep", etc.
```

Then I have a map where the keys are Strings (specifically, the same literal values as *some* of the animals in the array above), and the values are a count (representing the number of those animals):

```
Map<String,Integer> animalCounts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
animalCounts.put("sheep", 4);
animalCounts.put("dogs", 2);
animalCounts.put("cats", 0);
animalCounts.put("porcupines", null);
animalCounts.put("dolphins", 43);
```

I am trying to figure out how to use the Stream API to iterate over my `animals` array, and come up with a total number of animals. For instance, if my `animals` array had "sheep" and "dolphins" in it, then the total number of animals would be 4 + 43 = 47.

My best attempt so far:

```
int totalAnimals = Arrays.stream(animals)
    .reduce(
        0,
        (subtotal, animal) -> subtotal + animalCounts.get(animal));
```

However this yields a compiler error for the identity value of `0`:

> "*Required type: String*"

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Comment: why would you do this `animalCounts.put("porcupines", null);`? how is `null` different from `0`, and why is the key `porcupines` still required to be a part of that `Map` at the same time?

Comment: Clarification: Could "dogs" be part of the `animals` array twice? If, yes, would you sum up dogs count twice?

Comment: Thanks Naman, I personally would `put("porcupines", null)` on the map, but that is my situation: map entries exist with non-null keys but `null` values. And good point concerning duplicates in the `animals` array. Since my application guarantees this won't happen, I'd say its safe to just sum their counts duplicately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

You're using the 2-argument version of [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```java
T reduce(T identity,
         BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

As you can see, the identity value and the output has to be of the same type as the input, so it must be `String`.

Solution would be to use the 3-argument version of [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```java
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

---

As an alternative, you can do it like this:

```java
int totalAnimals = Arrays.stream(animals)
        .map(animalCounts::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

The stream returned by `Arrays.stream(animals)` is of type `Stream<String>`, while you are reducing the stream with an identity of zero which is an `int`.

A simple way of doing this is mapping each animal to its count, and reduce the resulting `Stream<Integer>` to its sum:

```
int totalAnimals = Arrays.stream(animals)
                         .map(animalCounts::get)
                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                         .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

Note the use of `getOrDefault(animal, 0)` in the map, because the array may have elements not present in the map.

Comment: Code fails with `NullPointerException`, since the map has explicit `null` value for `"porcupines"`, so `getOrDefault(...)` doesn't apply the default.

Comment: With the null filter in place, you might as well drop the `OrDefault` part and have the filter skip the "not found" entries, in which case you can change the lambda expression to a method reference.